# How to re-import iTunes into the Music app?

Tags: itunes, music, import

I have an iTunes music folder and would like to re-convert it to the Apple Music app so that it takes all iTunes settings, playlist, counts into the Music app.

Does anyone know how to re-initiate the re-import process. I also have previous iTunes libraries folder as well.

What I've tried:

- In the Apple Music app using the import process and selecting the `iTunes library.itl` and it doesn't work. also tried it with the previous iTunes libraries.

Comment: Which music application precisely?

Comment: @Ramhound It’s iTunes and the poster wants to import their files to the (Apple) Music app.

Comment: Is the Apple Music app a cloud app of some sort? If so, this may require resetting the Music apps library somehow. What is the reason why you are trying to re-import? Are there issues/errors in the library currently that you feel a re-import would resolve?

Comment: @music2myear Apple’s Music app is just iTunes. They rebranded it.

Comment: Ah. Will they next rebrand their mobile devices as "Phone" and "Pad"? lol Thanks @Giacomo1968, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: @music2myear They basically decoupled iPhone/iPad syncing from iTunes and let the Finder do it. They set the Music stuff into “Apple Music” or just the “Music” app but I never had to reimport anything. When I upgraded whatever macOS version that implemented that change, it was all transparent to me. I just did it and one second I was syncing with “iTunes” then the upgrade and I was syncing with the “Finder” and managing music with the “Music” app. And that was that. Unsure what this question is about. Someone wanting to import an old library that was not handled by the standard macOS update?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I "fixed" it with a work around.

In the “Music” folder there is a folder called “Previous Libraries” and I swapped an older library with the current library. It loaded and I lost only 400 changes. Good enough!

I'm assuming if you move the “Music” folder to the desktop then swap out the library file from “Previous iTunes Libraries” one should redo the import from iTunes to music.

This is good enough for now with a few changes lost but manageably “lost.”